# Google OAuth 2.0 authorising popup error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oauth, google-api, google-oauth

We are using OAuth 2.0 protocol for authorising our app, read the data from various G Suite products.

The authorisation was working absolutely fine last week. However this week we have couple of users who is facing a strange issue where the authorisation is not happening and it throws error "popup_closed_by_user" even if user haven't.

User is trying with chrome browser, no popup blocker is installed, not set chrome profile and not logged in with multiple accounts.

Below console error we are getting.

[image]

Google OAuth 2.0 for Client-side Web Applications reference [link](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent)
which we have followed.

Comment: I think the issue you are facing is that the popup is blocked by the browser.    The user may not know they have a popup blocker enabled.

Comment: @DaImTo User does not installed any popup blocker extension or app.